# Make divs walk left or right and finally disappear from the page

Tags: jquery, css

I have a web page with a four buttons menu bar. Each button click shows a different div. All the four divs are included in the same page(I do not use any second page except from index.html). I want the change among these divs to be done the way
http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wt_39361/index.html#!/page_about
does. My way is: absolute position to any div and apply

```
$('#content1').animate({ "left": "+=1500px" }, "slow" );
```

However, the result is not what I want since content1 walks to the right but it is still there visible with the horizontal scroll bar. How may I disappear #content1 and simultaneously appear #content2 the way I want?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, you want a viewport. The viewport would have an `overflow: hidden;` property and would be the width of the screen. The viewport could definitely be your `body` element, but it doesn't have to be-- the only stipulation is that the elements that are moving are contained within it.

You would fire your move function, your element would move off to the side of the screen and then bring in your other element in the same way, and after set it to `position: relative;` after the animation. Something like this:

```
var navClick = function() {
    $viewport = $('#viewport');
    $targetElem = $('#content' + $(this).data('target'));
    $active = $viewport.find('.active');
    $active.animate({'left': '-' + $active.width() + 'px'}, function() {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    });
    $targetElem.animate({'left': '100px'}, function() {
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
};

$(function() {
   $('nav span').on('click', navClick); 
});
```

Check it: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dV5FC/)